# WP7 accessing Freshbooks API through https is not working

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, https, httpwebrequest

I have this code which works in a windows console application, but does not work in windows phone 7.  I have already written an app for Basecamp that uses similar code, but I think the problem is related to FreshBooks HTTPS.  I have just spent several hours trying to make it work.

Basically the line using `var response = request.EndGetResponse(ar) as HttpWebResponse` throws an exception:

> The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

I can make a call successfully with curl and using the same code in a console application.  So, I know the problem is not with my api token, FreshBooks account or xml format!

```
private static void TestFreshbooks()
{
    var url = "https://XXXXXX.freshbooks.com/api/2.1/xml-in";
    HttpWebRequest request = CreateRequest(url);

    request.BeginGetRequestStream(CreateRequestCallback,
                                 new RequestState(null)
                                 {
                                     Request = request,
                                     Callback = (args) =>
                                     {
                                         Debug.WriteLine(args);
                                     },
                                 });
}

private static void CreateRequestCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var state = ar.AsyncState as RequestState;
    var request = state.Request;

    var xml = "<request method='client.list'></request>";

    using (Stream stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(ar))
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);// encoder.GetBytes(postData);
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    request.BeginGetResponse(CreateResponseCallback, state);
}

private static void CreateResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        var state = ar.AsyncState as RequestState;
        var request = state.Request;
        using (var response = request.EndGetResponse(ar) as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (var rs = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var sr = new StreamReader(rs);
                var results = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Debug.WriteLine(results);

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
    }
}


private static HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(string url)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url)) as HttpWebRequest;
    var token = "XXXXXXX";

    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    request.UserAgent = "freshwp7test";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(token, "X");

    return request;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours last night on this.  I figured in 3 minutes this morning.  It's amazing what some sleep will do to you.

It turns out that Fiddler was breaking the https traffic and screwing up the debugging.  I had to close fiddler and restart the emulator.

Thanks.